# Reliable access to locked remote computer

Tags: service, remote-access, restart, reliability, teamviewer

**What I have:** I have Windows 7 on my home PC.

**What I'm trying to do:** I'm trying to keep TeamViewer running at home so I can always get to my home computer.  The other day it got completely messed up and would not let me connect but everything else on the PC was just fine.

**Items I've looked at:**

I looked at this thread and it does not seem to apply to what I need:

[Is it possible to start Teamviewer, to accept connections, from commandline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154598/is-it-possible-to-start-teamviewer-to-accept-connections-from-commandline/16323024#16323024)

... but it does not appear to be what I'm looking for.

I have looked at this:

https://serverfault.com/questions/48600/how-can-i-automatically-restart-a-windows-service-if-it-crashes

... and to test the script at the above URL, I stopped a service on my computer and pointed the above vbs script to that service and the vbs script will not restart that service, so that's not working.

**What's happening:**

From time to time on my home computer, TeamViewer hangs or gets messed up in some way and I cannot connect to my home computer.  The last time this happened, the TeamViewer UI was still running but there was a little red dot next to the tray icon and the id numbers and password were blank in the UI so I had to right click and kill it and restart the computer and all was OK.

**What I'd like to do:**

Is there a way I can run some kind of script or something that will completely kill all TeamViewer processes and services and restart it completely?  I'd like to schedule this type of activity once an hour so I can be assured of pretty much always being able to get into my home computer or else just wait an hour and it should be back up and available?

I have 20 years in IT with networking background, databases, GUI development, website development, hardware and software installation but no experience in brain surgery.  I've given it a good try but am now asking for some help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that task scheduler, taskkill and batch script is your friend here.
create a batch file to stop any current team viewer process and then restart it.
crate a batch file something like:

```
taskkill /IM TeamViewer.exe 
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\TeamViewer.exe"
```

(substitute the path to TeamViewer.exe on your own machine).
Then create an hourly scheduled task to run the script using the highest privileges (using Windows Task Scheduler).

Lookup taskkill for more info on killing tasks from the command line.

Just to add that you'll have to have the PC in a associated in your teamviewer account in a group (e.g. My Computers) and use the same account to connect - otherwise the password change on restart will prevent you connecting (you won't know the new password).

Comment: Hi, @Charmer.  It's kinda odd - I went into the settings and I setup the unattended access feature with a password.  The ID in unattended is somehow the same as the id on the main screen of the GUI.  I have rebooted a few times and the ID remains the same on the GUI main screen AND in the unattended settings AND the unattended password remains the same.  Kinda odd but it's a happy accident.  I wonder if doing the task kill will change that - we'll see though.

Comment: Hi, @charmer.  I tried a batch file with just [taskkill /IM TeamViewer.exe] and a yellow bubble popped up over the tray saying that "TV is still running so you will be able to continue to connect remotely." - not an exact quote.  So for some reason taskkill was not powerful enough to kill the process / service.

Comment: I tried the method found here: [https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/312-stop-a-hung-service] by doing the [sc queryex teamviewer] and then getting the pid and plugging it into the [taskkill /f /pid [PID]] command and it told me that the prcess with [pid] as been terminated but then TV gui popped to the foreground, TV was still in the tray and still in the services list in Computer Management.

Comment: Hi @user2792497  When running taskkill did you use an elevated command prompt? check the settings for recovery if you have it running as a service take a look at the recovery tab on the service settings and disable recovery.  Looking at what is running for team viewer using task manager and find each exe. I found ; tv_x64.exe, tv_w32.exe, and TeamViewer_Service.exe.  The service will restart if service recovery is setup, so disable service recovery for TeamViewer_Service.

Comment: Hi @Charemer - First - my apologies for spelling your name incorrectly. TaskKill did not end up working for me however it MAY end up working for other folks so I'm going to mark your answer as the accepted answer. My solution was to create a .BAT file that executed SHUTDOWN -F - R -T 010 or something close to that which (F)orces a (R)estart after wating for a (T)ime of 10 seconds and then going to TaskScheduler and scheduling that BAT file to be kicked off at noon and 3pm every day. This way if there was some kind of hiccup I knew that it would "self fix" 2x per day.